# How should we deal with paging links in Rest

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I just started learning Rest architecture, and I have a question.

I have 10000 records (universities) , and I decide to render just one page with 100 records per request with links for paging.

If a client do GET http://blablabla/api/universities?take=500, what should I put on paging links (just two page?) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have 10000 records (universities) , and I decide to render just one page with 100 records per request with links for paging.

You want the [Feed Paging and Archiving](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005) specification.  If the pages are indefinitely stable, then you should consider the guidance on [archived feeds](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005#section-4), in addition to reviewing [paged feeds](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005#section-3).

Note that in a RESTful design, there's no particular urgency to give the client what they asked for.  It's perfectly reasonable to redirect the client to a different resource, and expect them to follow links from there

```
GET /api/universities?take=500&startingFrom=107

302 Found
Location: /api/universities/page2#107
```

"The representation you asked for may already be in your cache, and the paging links there will take you to the rest of it"

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for the links, I found many useful things for my project.